# Getting error while building a mule 4 project in jenkin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm doing setup of jenkin pipeline with the GitHub. setup has been done. Deployed mule 4 project in Git.
Jenkin checkout process is working properly but for build process i'm getting below mentioned error.

Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace E:\IDFC\github_checkoutCode
[github_checkoutCode] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8773003533490857843.bat

** E:\IDFC\github_checkoutCode>mvn clean install 
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\IDFC\github_checkoutCode>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE **

i have done environment variable setup MAVEN_HOME.
How can i Fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that Jenkins can not find the Maven command (mvn.bat in Windows). Probably you need to add the %MAVEN_HOME%/bin directory to the path.

I don't see any Mule related issues.